# Array.prototype.splice - help to understand a lesson

Tags: javascript

Here is a function from a tutorial:

```
function add() {
    var values = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, [1]),
        total = 0;

    for(var value of values) {
        total += value;
    }

    return total;
}
```

[**SOURCE**](https://leanpub.com/essentialtypescript/read#spread-operator)

And the expression `Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, [1])` confuses me.

1. Why `1`?
2. And why with brackets `[1]`?

If we pass 1, it represents `start` position in `splice()`, so it will skip the first argument we pass to `add()`, hence it won't add all arguments...

Is this a mistake in the tutorial?

Comment: `[1]` would just get coerced to `1` within `splice`. However, `apply` would make more sense than `call` (or, of course, `call`, but then `1` instead of `[1]`). And yes, this saves all arguments except the first one in `values`. Honestly, `slice` would make more sense here…

Comment: Thanks, @Xufox - but in either case (slice / splice), that `1` doesn't make sense, right? It should be 0, as I understand

Comment: Depends on the argument list passed to the add function really.

Comment: @fromZerotoHero I can just guess that it’s just an arbitrary example, even if it really doesn’t make complete sense.

Comment: Hm.. Well thats a bit weird

Comment: Theyve clearly copied their later example of a `calculate` method which uses the first argument as the operation and forgotten to correct it.

Comment: @Jamiec - good catch. Seems thats the story behind it

Comment: A tutorial that mixes `splice` and `arguments` with ES6 `for … of` syntax? Read a different tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: the example was made by simplyfing code of another function which had one special parameter and used `apply` instead of `call` in ES5 syntax.

In the further part of the tutorial, calculating functions are discussed, whose first argument determines the type of calculations to be performed. If you write them in the ES5 syntax, you'd have to delete the first argument. That explains *Why 1* - to delete the first argument. Now, *why brackets*: there are two nearly identical functions in JS: `call` and `apply`. See [this note about `apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of call(), the fundamental difference is that call() accepts an argument list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments.

I think the author of calculation function mistakenly used the syntax for `apply` and hence the brackets.

Answer (score 6):

Yes this example is mistaken, if you try the code it doesn't work (it ignores the first parameter) exactly as you said. The code would make sense if that line was:

```
var values = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
```

Or

```
var values = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0),
```

Comment: Did you mean `splice` or `slice`?

Comment: The first example I gave is `slice`, the second is `splice`

Comment: But only one of them makes sense.

Comment: They both work and make sense as written - I don't see any mistake in what I wrote?

Comment: I was referring to "*The code would make sense if that line was*". You should never mutate the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, calling the Array.prototype.splice with `[1]` is probably a mistake.

According to MDN docs for [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), this method's first argument is supposed to be a number. Chrome will indeed interpret `[1]` as `1` and skip the first argument.

You should check if the first argument is supposed to be skipped, otherwise better make your for loop directly over the function arguments.